# Warning : MPDF library does not exist

Tags: php, pdf, opencart, mpdf

I have downloaded the updated version of Mpdf and using it with open-cart. It is giving me the following warning:

> Warning : MPDF library does not exist, please download and upload. For
>   upload MPDF library

How can this warning be resolved? I don't think I can install composer on my live website. I uploaded the MPDF library in **system > library > mpdf** directory but issue still exists. Check following code:

```
    if(!is_file(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php')){
             $this->log->write('Warning : MPDF library does not exist, please download and upload it. for upload MPDF library https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf');
             echo 'Warning : MPDF library does not exist, please download and upload. For upload MPDF library <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf">Click here</a>';
             exit;
    }

   error_reporting(0);

   require_once(DIR_SYSTEM.'library/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please set mpdf library in `system librabry` directory